# Return variable from node.js to sh script

Tags: node.js, bash, sh

Is it possible to execute node.js app from .sh script, return some variable and continue the .sh script?
Something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
SOME_VARIABLE = node app.js
echo ${SOME_VARIABLE}
```

Comment: Probably, only that in the Bash side you need to say `var=$(command)`. That is, no spaces around `=`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly, ensure you're using `bash`, not `sh`, as there are significant differences in functionality between the two.

One simple solution is command substitution, although be aware that trailing newlines in the command output will be stripped. Also, when echoing, to protect the contents of the variable (such as spaces and glob characters) from metaprocessing by the shell, you have to double-quote it:

```
#!/bin/bash
output=$(node app.js);
echo "$output";
```

Another solution is process substitution in more recent versions of `bash`. You could even collect the output as an array of lines in this case:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3< <(node app.js);
lines=();
while read -r; do lines+=("$REPLY"); done <&3;
exec 3<&-;
echo "${lines[@]}";
```

Comment: sounds good! By the way, there is no need of semi colons at the end of every line

Comment: @fedorqui, you are 100% correct. However, it has always been my programming style to explicitly terminate every statement with a semicolon. Perhaps it's a carryover from my C/C++/Java experience, but I feel it helps make the code more readable and more clearcut, kind of like the programmer is explicitly stating that the statement is complete. Also, semicolons are required when coding multiple statements on the same line, so you could say it improves consistency as well.

Comment: @MrBinWin, several things in response: firstly, process substitution is inherently asynchronous, so within the `while` loop, you can decide if you've read enough output at any time, and then just stop reading (i.e. break the loop). The closure of the file descriptor (`&3`) I believe would be likely to terminate the writing process (`node.js`), depends on the design of `node.js`. But command substitution is synchronous, so there's so way to terminate the statement in the middle. There are other messy solutions, like background processes, but output collection is tricky there (e.g. files).